# How to import classes from Swift Cocoapod into Swift project?

Tags: swift, xcode, import, cocoapods

I've made own pod in Swift language (contains classes in Swift lang).
This pod is published.

I created new project and created pod (via `pod init`)
Edited it with pod name and version and with `use_frameworks!` line

After `pod install` it was downloaded.
So I can open `.xcworkspace` and see my pod in files in project.

But I can't import need classes in my project. How to do this?

Comment: all classes that I need to import have `public` key word in swift files

Comment: Simply add `import YourPodName` and you can access all public symbols.

Comment: it doesn't work, it says `consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'` (my pod has dashes in title)

Comment: if I'm trying to import specific class by name - it doesn't work either

Comment: That wont work, it has to be the name of the module. Expand the Pods project, then the Pods directory, then your pod and look under support files, you should see a `podname.modulemap`. Open that and look at the name of the module, thats what you should be importing in your code. If it has a dash in the name specify the module name in the podspec: `s.module_name = "YourPodNameNoDashes"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The last point works. Somehow in `.module` the pod name has underscore characters in title instead of real dash characters

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to import the module in the source files where you need it. `import ModuleName`.

As you mentioned in the comments you have invalid characters in your pod name for the import statement so they are likely replaced with underscores. To verify the module name you can expand your Pods project in the workspace, expand the directory for your pod, expand the Supoort Files and view `PodName.modulemap` for module name. If you are unhappy with the name created you can specify a module name in the pod spec file:

```
s.module_name = "FriendlyModuleName"
```

Comment: Pod name has dashed in title. But somehow in `.module` the pod name has underscore characters in title instead. Thanks again